# How to run two snapshot listeners functions same time on start and after it separately

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, listener, snapshot

I have two snapshot listeners and I need to run them in same completion block to get data to same array on first time when application starts. After application is started and listeners are listening I need to run functions separately. I cannot use completion block because if data changes on fetchOwnGames function it also calls another fetchFriendsGames function.

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
if games.count == 0 {
  self.fetchOwnGames {
    self.fetchFriendsGames {
      completion()
    }
  }
}
}
```

Also I cannot use dispatchGroup because if function completion called dispatchGroup.leave() function is getting error

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
if games.count == 0 {
  let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

  dispatchGroup.enter()
  fetchOwnGames {
    dispatchGroup.leave()

  }
  dispatchGroup.enter()
  fetchFriendsGames {
    dispatchGroup.leave()
  }

  dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    completion()
  }
}
}
```

How I can call functions separately but data comes same time.

Here is my fetchOwnGames and fetchFriendGames functions

```
  func fetchOwnGames(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    guard let ownUid = UserService.shared.currentUser?.id else { return }
    ownListener = Constants.FirebaseCollection.gamesCollection
      .order(by: "startTime")
      .whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: ownUid)
      .limit(toLast: 5)
      .addSnapshotListener { [self] querySnapshot, error in
        guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot, error == nil else {
          print("DEBUG: error", error?.localizedDescription as Any)
          return
        }
        querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEach { (change) in
          switch change.type {
          case .added:
            guard let data = try? change.document.data(as: Game.self) else { return }
            self.games.append(data)
            self.games = games.sorted(by: { $0.endTime.compare($1.endTime) == .orderedDescending})
            self.ownGames.append(data)
            SettingsManager.shared.gamesCount = ownGames.count
          case .modified:
            guard let data = try? change.document.data(as: Game.self) else { return }
            if let index = self.games.firstIndex(where: { $0.courseId == data.courseId }) {
              self.games[index] = data
            }
          case .removed:
            guard let data = try? change.document.data(as: Game.self) else { return }
            self.games = self.games.filter { $0 != data }
            self.games = games.sorted(by: { $0.endTime.compare($1.endTime) == .orderedDescending})
            SettingsManager.shared.gamesCount = games.count
          }
        }
        print("DEBUG2: owngames count", ownGames.count)
        completion()
      }
  }

  func fetchFriendsGames(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    userService.fetchFriends(friendCompletion:  { [self] friends in
      let friendsUidArray = friends.map { $0.id }
      if friendsUidArray.count == 0 {
        completion()
      } else {
        for uid in friendsUidArray {
          guard let uid = uid else { return }
          friendListener = Constants.FirebaseCollection.gamesCollection
            .order(by: "startTime", descending: true)
            .whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: uid)
            .limit(to: 5)
            .addSnapshotListener({ querySnapshot, error in
              guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot, error == nil else {
                print("DEBUG: error", error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                return
              }
              querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEach { change in
                switch change.type {
                case .added:
                  guard let data = try? change.document.data(as: Game.self) else { return }
                  self.games.append(data)
                  self.friendGames.append(data)
                  self.games = games.sorted(by: { $0.startTime.compare($1.startTime) == .orderedDescending})
                case .modified:
                  guard let data = try? change.document.data(as: Game.self) else { return }
                  if let index = self.games.firstIndex(where: { $0.courseId == data.courseId }) {
                    self.games[index] = data
                  }
                case .removed:
                    guard let data = try? change.document.data(as: Game.self) else { return }
                    self.games = self.games.filter { $0 != data }
                    self.games = games.sorted(by: { $0.endTime.compare($1.endTime) == .orderedDescending})
                }
              }
              print("DEBUG3: friendgames count", friendGames.count)
              completion()
            })

        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: "How I can call functions separately but data comes same time."  It doesn't sound like a good plan.

Comment: Got it work by adding:   private var appStarted = false and using if !self.appStarted in dispatch group. dispatchGroup.enter()
      fetchOwnGames {
        if !self.appStarted {
          dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
      }
      dispatchGroup.enter()
      fetchFriendsGames {
        if !self.appStarted {
          dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
      }

      dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.appStarted = true
        completion()
      }. Don't know how good solution this is

Comment: @tonileipo if you already found a solution can you post it as an answer for visibility?

Comment: Did it now. there

Answer (score 1):

Got it work with adding boolean checker.

```
private var appStarted = false

func fetchData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
if games.count == 0 {
  let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

  dispatchGroup.enter()
  fetchOwnGames {
    if !self.appStarted {
      dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
  }
  dispatchGroup.enter()
  fetchFriendsGames {
    if !self.appStarted {
      dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
  }

  dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    self.appStarted = true
    completion()
  }
}
}
```